# How can I get sql string, generated by Linq2SQL ORM?

Tags: linq-to-sql

So, actually this is a main question : How can I get sql string, generated by Linq2SQL ORM?
I am familiar with other ORM systems, such as nHibernate and EntityFramework (4+).
For instance, for nHibernate exist [profiler](http://nhprof.com/) witch allow to catch any activity, performing by nHibernate engine. In the other hand, EntityFramework has build-in functionality - method

```
query.ToSqlString()
```

And what about Linq2SQL?

Comment: Your question is just about linq-to-sql, so please remove the other tags (entity-framework and nhibernate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @usr mentions, you can use `ToString()` on the query to get the generated SQL. You can also use the [`Log` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) on the linq data context to dump [all SQL commands](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/profiling_linq_to_sql_using_th.html).

Another general option is to use the SQL Server Profiler to watch all queries as they come in to the server. That will work for all ORM.